# Can you copy files from virtualbox without vbox running?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hardware-failure

I got into a big trouble now. My hard disk just kind of "crashed". I get from disks that "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL".

My main OS is ubuntu, and I am (or was) using a Windows 7 VBOX. When I start ubuntu, it freezez. I know it's the hard-disk for sure.

I am on superuser.com now from an ubuntu live cd. I don't have any backup of my hard-disk (yep, I know...) so I could backup my files from ubuntu, but I also have some important files on my VBOX. Is there any way to copy the VBOX or, get files from it without it running ?

Answer (score 0):

So you are booted off a LiveCD and it sounds like you are able to copy data from your hard drive.  If that is the case, then all you need to do is copy the .VMDK file that was created when you made the Windows virtual machine.  This file is the virtual hard drive.  Once you have that file, you can boot the Windows VM on any other machine running Virtualbox.

Comment: Where do I find it ?

Comment: home/.VirtualBox I believe